# What do the keywords in the eventful api map to?

Tags: python

I have been trying to setup the eventful api using python.  The following example is all the documentation I could find on the it:

```
import eventful

api = eventful.API('your API key here')

# If you need to log in:
# api.login('username', 'password')

events = api.call('/events/search', q='music', l='San Diego')
for event in events['events']['event']:
    print "%s at %s" % (event['title'], event['venue_name'])
```

What does the `q` and `l` stand for in the `api.call()` method?

[Here is the link to the python](https://api.eventful.com/libs/python/)

[The eventful API documentation](https://api.eventful.com/docs)

Comment: Did you open the [documentation](https://api.eventful.com/docs/events/search) page? It seems that `l` is location and `q` should be something else listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what the args stood for,
this link has them:

http://api.eventful.com/tools/tutorials/search

*What: The 'what' argument, also called **'q'** or 'keywords', is used to search by any aspect of an event that isn't part of the category, location or time.*

*Where: The 'where' argument, also called **'l'** or 'location', is used to search by city, region, postal code (ZIP), country, street address, or venue. It's often used in concert with the 'within' and 'units' parameters to do a radius search.*